# Search database using sqlite versus NSPredicate

Tags: sql, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm building a database in sqlite with multiple tables. It will work like a tag based search where CARS will be compared based on how many TAGS match between them. There will also be one layer used to categorize items called MANUFACTURER. So a typical use case would be user selects MANUFACTURER1 (lets say Ford) as an input and MANUFACTURER2 (lets say Toyota) as an output, enters a CAR [database compares TAGS to CARS between the two MANUFACTURERS] and fectches a CAR recommendation of MANUFACTURER2. I am using Core Data with entities of each, but this does not involve newly created objects, just what's in the original sql database.

My question is - is it better to generate the search with SQLite code, or `NSPredicate`/`NSCompoundPredicate`? Are there performance differences?

Comment: Why not just try both approaches?

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe you have this question clear but with CD you cannot use plain sql queries...

Comment: @flexaddicted - It's not that hard to set up a SQL db.  He can start using the `sqlite3` command in a PC or Mac command window, construct a toy DB, "play" with queries.  This would only take 30 minutes or so, if you knew what you were doing, but in part the purpose of the exercise would be to *learn* (from, eg, the [SQLite web site](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), so the added time is not wasted.

Comment: One important thing I should mention is I am a newbie and I don't know what I'm doing in sql or core data but am eager to learn the best approach. From what I understand I can use sql in core data if I have a wrapper. If you were in my shoes would go the mixed route of sql and core data or purely write it in core data?

Comment: Also I'm using code data in the first place for data persistence of features like recent searches and favorites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Core Data with a SQlite store, the `NSFetchRequest` with a specific predicate will be resolved at the sql level, so you don't need to add nothing to it.

Core Data will abstract this for you. If you use Core Data you cannot use your own query. Just stick with `NSFetchRequest`s and `NSPredicate`s.

Maybe what you need it's to import the db you have in the actual Core Data store.

Maybe I cannot understand your question but what's your goal?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've read ID related tasks may suffer in CoreData, and I hope to link the tables of CAR (id and car) and TAG (id and tag) with tables that link CAR to TAG (car_id and tag_id). So basically a lot of ID's happening. Would this still be effective/possible in coredata?

Comment: Yes of course. Setting up a many-to-many relationship between the two will be ok... @user3411663